# Hided status bar, but it's now replaced with white bar (iPhone Interface XIB)

Tags: iphone, user-interface, sdk, xib

I've used this code to hide the status bar

[application setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

On the view xib I have set the status bar to 'none' so there is no status bar.

When i run the app, the status bar has disappeared with the carrier, battery info etc. But is now a white bar, so in essence the status bar is there, but is white.

I have also tried changing it via the p list. But by me doing this, all my objects move 'up' and the sizing messes up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to set the statusBar hidden before you set the `self.window` frame, something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [application setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

//rest of the code here

return YES;
}
```

Doing so the window seems to position itself without leaving space for the StatusBar, thus filling the whole screen

Comment: Just wondered if I wanted to do the same in landscape, which values would change?

Comment: you won't have to change anything, if you rotate to landscape the view will resize properly filling the whole screen

Comment: The view is already landscape, with the code applied it seems that the view has took -20 pixels landscape, so it's eaten into the background. and the white bar at the top remains there.

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

Comment: Hey, it didn't work `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    [application setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];


    return YES;
}`

Comment: The white bar remains there still.

Answer (score 0):

Without the status bar you have a 20x320 points rectangle to work with. Your view sizing needs to adjust to this, and then you need to fill that space with something. Of course your views will move 'up' and your sizing get messed up. So what are you gonna put there?

Comment: But the white space isn't 'shown' on the xib because I've set it to none. So can how I fill the space, on the xib, it just shows the background fully stretched out within the pixels

Comment: Change your frame size in the view inspector.